# How can I add multiple Silverlight libraries with same WCF RIA service to one Silverlight application?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, shared-libraries

I use domain service, both of my Silverlight library projects are linked to same WCF RIA service.

When I added both libraries to the same Silverlight application, this error was raised.

> The type 'KhorasanMIS.Web.Services.Workflow.DSWorkflow' exists in both 'D:\KhorasanMIS\KhorasanMIS\KhorasanMISControls\Bin\Debug\KhorasanMISControls.dll' and 'D:\KhorasanMIS\KhorasanMIS\WorkflowLibrary\Bin\Debug\WorkflowLibrary.dll'  D:\KhorasanMIS\KhorasanMIS\Workflow\Models\General\MWorkState.cs'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The libraries you added to your Silverlight project contain references to dlls also referenced in your main Silverlight project?

in the class library projects in visual studio solution explorer > right click on the problem references and click on properties > set Copy Local to false.

Comment: Thank your john, Each of the liberaries and Silverlight project linked to one web application for WCF RIA Services. When i set WCF RIA Services link in properties window on project, how can i set copy local as false?

Comment: when I had this problem is was down to PRSIM dlls I had reference I was using in multiple projects which were part of a larger Silverlight project.  You may have to wrap your WCF service in a infrastructure or service class library, then use that library in each of your projects.